# button toggles between states

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering if anyone knew of some code which implements two buttons where one is just plain text and the other is say a link. When the user clicks on the link the other text becomes a button and vice versa when the user clicks the link again.

Think of it like this: One link is active the other isn't. One is a listview link and the other is a gridview text and when you click listview that link becomes text and the gridview text becomes a link. Does anyone know of an example that implements this kind of behavior or can someone show me an example in jQuery?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980410/multiple-jquery-toggle-links

Comment: I haven't posted this question before @P.Brian Mackey

Comment: @KDM: That does not mean that *you* posted the question before, only that your problem might be covered by an already asked question.

Comment: What is a *listview link* and a *gridview text*? Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/u9zfT/

Let me know what questions you have. This is pretty basic jQuery, so I'm not sure where you're getting tripped up.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the text in a span with a particular id.  When the link is clicked the .html for the span changes to a button.  Clicked again and the span is changed back to text.  Let me know if you need some code and I'll put something together for you.

Comment: Yeah if you could put something together for me that would be appreciated heaps.

Comment: I think it's better to have both the text and button already on the page, and then just show/hide them. It offers easier to maintain JS, and you don't end up having to remove and add elements to the DOM, which can reduce further complications (such as losing events that you want bound to the elements, etc).

Comment: If you can put it up on jsFiddle aswell so I can see a working example thanks

Comment: @KDM entered a good example on jsFiddle that should get you started.